# Como hacer una Suma con Ciclo For

Tags: c#

Necesito mostrar los números del 1 al 10 con el ciclo `for` y a la vez mostrar el resultado de la suma de todos los números y con un solo `label`, mi código es el siguiente:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    lblResultado.Text = lblResultado.Text + i.ToString() + " ";
    int Suma = 0;
    for (int numero = 1; numero <= 10; numero++) {
        Suma += numero;
        lblRSuma.Text = lblRSuma.Text + Suma.ToString(numero + " ");
        lblRSuma.Text = ("La sumatoria es : " + Suma);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué intentaste? Si no sabes programar, este no es el mejor sitio para aprender desde 0.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añádenos ese detalle.

Comment: Ese es todo el código?

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje es este? No estarás programando en C#?

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien tu problema, hay que:

1. Mostrar los números del 1 al 10
2. Mostrar el resultado de sumar del 1 al 10

Por alguna razón tienes un enredo en tu código y ocupas 2 for. Es como si los 2 problemas los tuvieras solucionado por separado y no supiste juntarlos.

```
int Suma = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    lblResultado.Text = lblResultado.Text + i.ToString() + " ";
    Suma += i;
} 
lblRSuma.Text = ("La sumatoria es : " + Suma);
```

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una forma diferente de resolver tu problema pero sin usar un **ciclo for** (se que tú ejercicio pide resolverse con un **ciclo for**, yo solo te propongo otra vía).

Para resolver una sumatoria puedes usar la **fórmula matemática n(n + 1) / 2**, donde **n** es el límite superior de la secuencia numérica, en tu caso **n** es **10**. Por tanto tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
int n = 10;
double n = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;

lblResultado.Text = n.ToString();
```

Comment: Siento decirle que le contestaste a alguien que nunca volvio al sitio luego de preguntar esto...

Comment: @gbianchi mi respuesta no es para el, es para cualquiera que vea útil mi respuesta

Comment: si la pregunta fuera sobre sumatorias.. pero es sobre ciclos for ;)...